# In SQLAlchemy is it possible to dump and load from a Table (not from a mapped class)?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pickle

---

**TL;DR** Using [SQLAlchemy](http://sqlalchemy.org) is it possible to do a [`dumps(…)` and `load(…)`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/serializer.html#sqlalchemy.ext.serializer.dumps) using a [`Table`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Table) (not a [mapped class](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapping_styles.html#declarative-mapping))? Just to clarify, I wrote those [two tiny tests (currently red)](https://gist.github.com/cuducos/5b3d98655c046099652cbaff23893844) to make my point.

---

Having this mapped class and session:

```py
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.ext.serializer import loads, dumps
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapper, scoped_session
from sqlalchemy.orm.session import sessionmaker


engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=False)
Base = declarative_base(bind=engine)
session = scoped_session(sessionmaker())



class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = Column(String(140), index=True, unique=True)
```

Using the `User` mapped class I can dump and load data:

```
>>> # create a record
>>> Base.metadata.create_all()
>>> session.add(User(email='john@alchemydumps'))
>>> session.commit()
>>>
>>> # use dumps
>>> with open('dummy_file', 'wb') as file_handler:
...     file_handler.write(dumps(session.query(User).all()))
...
490
>>>
>>> # reset the database
>>> Base.metadata.drop_all()
>>> Base.metadata.create_all()
>>>
>>> # use loads
>>> with open('dummy_file', 'rb') as file_handler:
...     for row in loads(file_handler.read()):
...         session.merge(row)
...
<__main__.User object at 0x10977ea20>
>>> session.commit()
>>> 
>>> # assert data is back
>>> session.query(User).count()
1
>>>
```

But using a `Table` instead does **not** work:

```
>>> …
>>>
>>> # use a table instead (User.__table__, instead of User)
>>> with open('dummy_file', 'wb') as file_handler:
...    file_handler.write(dumps(session.query(User.__table__).all()))
...
115
>>> Base.metadata.drop_all()
>>> Base.metadata.create_all()
>>>
>>> with open('dummy_file', 'rb') as file_handler:
...     for row in loads(file_handler.read()):
...         session.merge(row)
...
```

This code crashes with an `sqlalchemy.orm.exc.UnmappedInstanceError`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
File "/Users/cuducos/.virtualenvs/alchemydumps/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/scoping.py", line 157, in do
    return getattr(self.registry(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/cuducos/.virtualenvs/alchemydumps/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1702, in merge
    object_mapper(instance)  # verify mapped
File "/Users/cuducos/.virtualenvs/alchemydumps/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/base.py", line 266, in object_mapper
    return object_state(instance).mapper
File "/Users/cuducos/.virtualenvs/alchemydumps/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/base.py", line 288, in object_state
    raise exc.UnmappedInstanceError(instance)
sqlalchemy.orm.exc.UnmappedInstanceError: Class 'sqlalchemy.util._collections.KeyedTuple' is not mapped
```

This message is already too long, so I avoided talking much about the context of the probelm. But I do have [a situation](https://github.com/cuducos/alchemydumps/issues/13) in which I need to dump and load non-mapped classes… and I'm trying to find a solution for that. (*Disclaimer: I wrote this package 2 years ago when I was a newbie in Python; yeah, the code looks terrible — but I have been fully refactoring it in the last weeks.*)

Any ideas or recommendations for this newbie in SQLAlchemy?

Comment: You can't use `session.merge` if you're not using mapped classes.

Comment: Thanks, @univerio. Is there an alternative though? How would you load something not using a mapped class (if that is possible)?

Comment: What do you mean by load? If you mean "reconstruct the resultset" you've already done that after you do `loads`; session.merge is unnecessary.

Comment: @univerio I had some data in the dumps, taken from a `Table`. Is it possible to to restore that data back in the `Table` (in case of a backup/restore, soma data was lost, sync and stuff like that). That's what I mean…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After @univerio's comments I could better understand the situation and fixed, yay!

The thing is that if the SQLAlchemy `dumps` receives a `Table` instance, the results are not related to the table, they are purely a [`KeyedTuple`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.util.KeyedTuple). So I had to:

1. *bring in* a mapped class when it was a `KeyedTuple` load
2. *transform* the `KeyedTuple` into a dictionary (which is easy, as `KeyedTuple` has a `_asdict()` method)
3. and then *merge* (as it was originally my intention)

The [tests are now green](https://gist.github.com/cuducos/5b3d98655c046099652cbaff23893844/revisions), but to summarize this is what I needed:

```
with open('dummy_file', 'rb') as file_handler:
...     for row in loads(file_handler.read()):
...         if isinstance(row, KeyedTuple):
...             row = User(**row._asdict())
...         session.merge(row)
>>> session.commit()
```

Comment: Just a note: `KeyedTuple` has been [replaced by `Row`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/changelog/migration_14.html?highlight=keyedtuple#change-4710-orm) in SQLA 1.4+.